# How do I check whether a double variable has more than two decimals in Java?

Tags: java, decimal

I thought I could accomplish this easily with something such as the following:

```
double numInput;

numInput = Double.parseDouble(inputTxtField.getText());

if ((numInput * 100) % 1 != 0) {

// do something

}
```

However, I'm getting all sorts of strange test cases where such as:

> false:
>   2.11,
>   2.5,
>   2.6
>
> true:
>   2.22, 2.3, 2.2

I just started programming so maybe this is a silly goof, but I thought multiplying a double by 100 and then checking for a remainder when dividing by 1 would work. The intent is to prevent someone from entering a number with more than two decimals. Less than or equal to 2 decimals is fine.

Any tips are appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: Thank you for all the quick comments! This solved my problem, and I really appreciate the extra information as to why it won't work. Thank you!

Comment: I did not understand very well the problem, and above all, put the complete code

Comment: get index of '.' and minus that from the length of the double heh

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I would just check the string input with a regex (`^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{0,2}$`), before you convert it to a double.

Comment: `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(doubleNumber)).scale() > 2`. Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/java-separate-double-into-integer-decimal-parts

Answer (score 17):

Convert to `BigDecimal` and check the `scale`:

```
double[] values = { 2.11, 2.5, 2.6, 2.22, 2.3, 2.2, 3.141 };
for (double value : values) {
    boolean fail = (BigDecimal.valueOf(value).scale() > 2);
    System.out.println(value + "  " + (fail ? "Fail" : "Pass"));
}
```

*Output*

```
2.11  Pass
2.5  Pass
2.6  Pass
2.22  Pass
2.3  Pass
2.2  Pass
3.141  Fail
```

Comment: This would be the correct approach. `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(doubleNumber)).scale() > 2`. Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/java-separate-double-into-integer-decimal-parts

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera The [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-) used in the answer is implemented as `return new BigDecimal(Double.toString(val));`, so what this old answer shows **is** the *correct approach*, and has been since it was added in **Java 1.5**. It uses the convenience method, supplied by the Java Runtime Library, to keep the code simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if(inputTxtField.getText().indexOf(".") >= 0 && inputTxtField.getText().indexOf(".") < inputTxtField.getText().length() - 2){
```

It will be `true` when there is a decimal in the original `String` that is before the last 2 characters in the `String`.

Comment: This fails if user types `123.4500`, even though that number is technically good.

Comment: @Andreas: The question was about checking that there were 2 decimal places, which isn't true for that input, even if they are zeros. Even if your input is valid, it can be solved by things like making a regex that allows any number of zeros at the end. Anyway, the general idea of validating the input text is much saner than converting it to a double and then trying to reason about it, +1.

Comment: @NathanHughes The question is "double **variable** has more than two decimals". The question isn't asking how to check the text field, even though that is the source of the value. Now, a good answer can suggest that *as an alternative*, but this answer deviated from the question without notice.

Comment: @Andreas: since the OP seems to be unaware of the representation issues I think it's hard to know what the question really is about.

Answer (score 3):

This won't work. Computers work in binary. Remember that 1/3 equals 0.33333333 with infinite digits. The computer can only store a finite number of binary digits, so it cuts after some digits. This means that 1/3 * 3 != 1. Same goes for any number in binary, that means 1/100 * 100 is not 1, because you just lost some decimal places. Working with double you will never be able to use the standard = or != operators, because they won't work most of the time.

The best way to solve this in your case is to work with the String directly and look at the position of the '.' character.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `compareTo` from the `Double` class

```
Double numInput;
Double foo = numInput*100;
foo = foo - foo.intValue();

if (foo.compareTo(0D) > 0 ) {

   //has more than two digits

}
```